# Python upgrade!

Tags: upgrade, python3

Using `dpkg --list` I see that I got all different packages of python, but when I use `python -V` it shows only one specific package, let's say, `python 2.7.1` , does this mean that this latter is the python version in use? if yes how can I upgrade the package in use to `python 3.5` for instance?
By the way I am on ubuntu 15.10

Thanks a bunch

Comment: There is no python version "in use". Applications either call 2 or 3. Try python3 -V. Both are on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 and 3 coexist on all current Ubuntu releases (btw. 15.10 is outdated, you should upgrade to 16.04 or 16.10).

To distinguish them, the commands are `python2` and `python3` respectively. The plain `python` command is just a symlink to one of those. Which one depends on the OS you use, on Ubuntu it's still always Python 2, but other distributions like Arch Linux or Gentoo may default to Python 3 already.

Comment: That's what I said. Nowhere I suggested to change that @JacobVlijm

Comment: Edited the answer and clarified it.